# How do I specify mounted windows shares as a command line path?

Tags: gnome, windows, command-line, samba

I can connect to a Windows server using the **Gnome Places -> Connect to ...** dialog, and then I can access the files using Nautilus.

Now, how can I specify a file or folder in the share on a command line? For example, I have this share "`c$ on WinServer`". I would like to specify this location as a path for commands like `ls`, `cp` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls ~/.gvfs`

That'll show gnome-mounted things and you can treat them like any other filesystem.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.